# Bundle typescript output in single file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, module, bundle

I have a bunch of typescript files following ecmascript 2015 module pattern in source folder. I have tsconfig setup to output the transpiled files to lib folder. That works good. But is there any way to bundle them together into a sigle file that can be used in the browser? I want my module to be available via npm and also as a script tag.

Refer to [my dummy github project](https://github.com/codeblue404/npm-module/) for details. tried the gulp-typescript, concat, uglify way, but in vain.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) with [ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader) to compile TypeScript and create a single bundle:

1. Install webpack

   ```
   > npm install webpack ts-loader --save-dev
   ```
2. Create **webpack.config.js**

   ```
   const path = require('path');
   module.exports = {
      entry: "./src/index.ts",
      output: {
          filename: "bundle.js",
          path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
      },
      resolve: {
          extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".js"]
      },
      module: {
          rules: [{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ts-loader" }]
      }
   }
   ```
3. Run webpack

   ```
   > webpack
   ```
4. You may also need to install webpack-cli (messages will tell you as you go to run the `webpack` command)

   ```
   > npm install webpack-cli
   ```

See the documentation on webpack and ts-loader for more as configuration options change over time.

Comment: I am actually creating a library. So this is a definitely a good start. But i will need to separate the location of transpiled js and bundled js. Also need support for both node and browser environments. I am considering to incorporate gulp which will create  the js, and then apply webpack wiith advanced options to create library bundles from the js, without needing ts-loader. What's your opinion?