# "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined" in HTML5 boilerplate

Tags: javascript, typescript

I created an HTML5 Boilerplate project in WebStorm. When I want to run it I use `localhost:8080/myproject/src` URL. In the `src` folder I have a `js` folder with the following structure:

```
libraries
models
    place.model.ts
      place.model.js
    address.model.ts
      address.model.ts
main.ts
  main.js
```

Typescript compiler converts the .ts files to .js

Inside my .model.ts files I have the following code:

```
export class MyClass {
    x: string;
    constructor(x: string) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

And then in my main.ts I import it:

```
import {MyClass as My} from "./models/myclass.model";
```

When I try to run the URL - I'm getting this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`. I look at the compiled main.js file and see this line added:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

I tried to solve it by inserting the following script in my index.html file:

```
<script>var exports = {};</script>
```

But then I got this error message: `ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

What am I missing and how do I make it work?

**UPDATE**
The project initially didn't have tsconfig file, so I added one manually. Here's the content:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I tried it without `"module": "commonjs"`, but it didn't help.

Comment: please share your tsconfig.json

Comment: You need to prepare your code for browser. Do you use webpack or browserify or something else for that?

Comment: Probably you should check this first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45112655/bundle-typescript-output-in-single-file

Comment: @GrzegorzMotyl I updated the question with the tsconfig part. Thanks!

Comment: @Drag13 Nope, not using any. Unfortunately not familiar with them, thought the boilerplate should work 'as is'. Checking the link, thanks!

Comment: @Drag13 I tried it with Webpack, here's the content of mine: `module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/main.ts",
  output: {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".js"]
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ts-loader" }]
  }
}`, but constantly getting a `path is not defined` error. Tried to resolve it for over an hour, updated node, npx etc - nothing worked, still the same error.

Comment: try add `var path = require('path');.` in webpack.config.js

Comment: did path help? what webpack version did you try?

Comment: @GrzegorzMotyl I did try it. Got this huge error message in red: `Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:`

Comment: @GrzegorzMotyl The rest of the message: `object { defaultRules?, exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, noParse?, rules?, strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?, unkno
wnContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp? }
   -> Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).
 - configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.
   -> A non-empty string`

Comment: @Drag13 Unfortunately it didn't, see the answer above to Grzegorz Motyl. Using WP ver . 4.20.2

Comment: Will it help if I put the project in Github or Bitbucket?

Comment: github will be the best option

Comment: @Drag13 Here it is: https://github.com/Igal-Kleiner/TorinoGuide

Comment: I am quite sure this boilerplate is not for TypeScript. It has no typescript, no bundler, even folder named js... Or this is worst ts template ever :) So, my option is take another ts template or write your own. I use this for my own experiments https://github.com/Drag13/typescript-browserify-template

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181107/discussion-between-igal-and-drag13).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when I first tried to use Webpack, I used configuration for older version of it. Once I changed the configuration - everything worked as it's supposed to. I was also able to configure a watcher for .ts files changes.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/main',
  mode: 'development',
  watch: true,
  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 600,
    poll: 1000,
    ignored: /node_modules/
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js', '.tsx', '.json']
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/js')
  }
}
```